# Are there limitations on deploying an MDB in a JBoss WAR?

Tags: jboss, war, message-driven-bean

We are not seeing our Message Driven Bean receive any messages when deployed in a war in JBoss 4.2.3. Are there any known limitations on using MDBs in WAR deployments?

Comment: EJB 3.1 supports EJB deployment in .war files. The fact that yours doesn't receive messages could be because a number of reasons, e.g. wrong web.xml file configuration (take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213174/jboss-6-deploy-ejb-in-war-packaging). Is your MDB getting deployed in JBoss, i.e. can you see that it is assigned a JNDI name in the deployment logs?

Comment: It looks like JBoss 4.2.3 uses EJB 3.0. Your linked question suggests that deployment in a war file is new to 3.1, so I'm guessing it is a limitation of our version. Thanks! (if you want to post as an answer, I'll accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above, EJB war deployment is only allowed from EJB 3.1 onwards.